# Finder randomly changes language in sidebar favourites

Tags: macos, finder, osx-el-capitan

I  have a pretty weird problem. I have an iMac and have just had my old HDD replaced with an SSD. The old HDD is now in my optical drive's slot.

I have a clean installation of El Captain on my SSD. Unfortunately, the guys who swapped the drives for me installed El Captain in Polish. Now I changed the OS language to English as I'm more used to it, and this is what my Finder does.

[image]

I still have an old OS installed on the other disk, which is not formatted yet. I thought that it might be by some miracle conflicting with the new installation, but Finder does this even after unmounting the old HDD.

I have absolutely no idea what to do with this, and it gets very annoying.

Has anyone had this problem before? Uncle Google brings no answers on this one :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the solution! 
This turned out to be an issue with a damaged ram stick. mac was in service for two weeks, they were pulling their hair over it, checking every component, and it turns out it's the simplest issue to fix ever.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the system and did two things and some weird behaviour including this phenomenon stopped. I installed the [Java for OS X 2015](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US) and reseted the NVRAM three times with pressing Option-Command-P-R at the booting phase until you hear the startup sound a second time.
Now everything seems to work again more stable and smoother, including Firefox, Finder and some other programmes.

Hi, unfortunately it didn't solve the issue completely. Still when I press Save in other programmes it does the same language change. Also Finder uses sometimes quite an intense amount of energy together with Firefox and they both crash quite often. So maybe with further beta updates this bug might be fixed or somebody else knows how to fix it.

Comment: Interesting! I too have major issues with Finder and, in my case, Chrome. They hang often and also use insane amounts of resources. I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: Nope, that didn't help unfortunately. i'm still stuck.